# Traverse, copy & transform file names

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

My issue: I need to copy log files, all with identical names, but stored 1-deep in subdirectories, and change their names.

I'm copying from the a folder called Logfiles which contains a bunch of folders:

`W3SVC114`, `W3SVC1507562355`, `W3SVC350179472`, etc.

Each of these folders will contain a file named: `u_ex[YYMMDD].log`, where [YYMMDD] is a datestamp.

I need all of these logfiles in one folder. Since all names are identical I would like to add the directory name to the resulting file name, for example:

`W3SVC1507562355/u_ex150407.log` becomes `W3SVC1507562355_u_ex150407.log`

How do I make all of these happen? I'm a bit out of my depth here...  :-/

Comment: Are we 'talking' Windows or Linux/Unix here?

Answer (score 2):

[Zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) comes with a function called [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) that makes it easy to move or copy files and apply pattern-based transformations on the name. Put this in your `.zshrc` (or run it on the command line):

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

Then your copy-with-renaming can be done with any of the following equivalent commands:

```
zcp 'Logfiles/(*)/(*.log)' 'destination_directory/${1}_$2'
zcp -w 'Logfiles/*/*.log' 'destination_directory/${1}_${2}.log'
zcp -W 'Logfiles/*/*.log' 'destination_directory/*_*.log'
```

If you don't want to install zsh, you can do the same thing with a loop in any shell:

```
cd Logfiles
for x in */*.log; do
  cp -- "$x" "destination_directory/${x%/*}_${x##*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following script to copy files from one location to another with modified name.

Note: In following script we have hard-coded two values.

1. **/Logfiles/** :- change Logfiles name to valid folder name from which you have to copy files.
2. **/tmp/** :- It is a directory under which you want to copy files. Change this directory name according to your requirements.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   find /Logfiles/ -maxdepth 1  -type f |  #find all files located under folder Logfiles with maxdepth one.

   while read FILEDIR                          #Read all files line by line.

   do

      DIR="${FILEDIR%/*}"                   # Get the folder name its inside
   #       echo $DIR

      FILE="${FILEDIR/*\/}"                 # Get the plain file name.
   #    echo $FILE

      NEWFILE="${DIR}"_"${FILE}"           # set new filename.
   #       echo $NEWFILE

      echo -e "coping $FILE from $DIR in /tmp with name $NEWFILE \n"


     cp $DIR/$FILE /tmp/$NEWFILE     #copy file from old location to new location with modified name.           


   done
   ```

Comment: @Evert Meulie Please mark answer as correct if you find solution useful.

Comment: Using `find` here even though no recursion is wanted is overkill and overcomplication. At least put double quotes around variable substitutions and use `IFS= read -r` to avoid gratuitously breaking on file names with spaces and other special characters

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your inputs. Those are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/pax.html):

```
pax -'rws|/|_|' -- */u_ex150407.log target/dir
```

`pax` is the standard file-archiver specified by POSIX. Unfortunately - though it is required in the [Linux Standard Base](http://www.linuxbase.org/betaspecs/lsb/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html#AEN57420) and has been for a few version increments of same - for whatever reason, many distribtions do not package it with the default installation as both standards require. I consider this a shame, because it is a very versatile tool.

Above I tell `pax` to go into `-r`ead and `-w`rite mode *(which translates to a copy)* and - when naming its output files - to `-s`ubstitute the first `/` in any of its named copy file parameters with a `_`. You can basically do standard BRE `sed` syntax there *(except that literal newlines in the left-hand-side are permissible here)*, but there's no need for anything elaborate in this case.

Anyway, that's all you need. If you don't have it installed for some reason, I recommend you get it and give `pax` a try.

Answer (score 1):

Plain POSIX shell answer:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in */*.log
do mv "$i" "${i//\//_}"
done
```

moves every file matching `*/*.log` to the same name with `/` substituted by `_`.

Comment: And if you want to see what it's moving, just add `-v` to the `mv` command.